# Flutter: Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode, flutter, dart

It's an app in production. I've changed some logic trying to obtain dateTime that I have localized changing it to another country, then suddenly there were some error saying something about dart html but I don't remember exactly what, so I tried to rebuild the project and it was complaining about using new build system and so far I tried:

- changing the system to legacy
- flutter clean
- udate cocoapods.
- remove podfile.lock
- pod update
- pod install
- packages upgrade
- flutter upgrade

None of theses did the work.

When changed to legacy there were like 13 errors one of them complaining that dart:html not found, so I've added it to dependencies and dev dev dependencies and still nothing.
I also commented the intl package because I was using it when that happened and did packages get and nothing.

Any ideas how to deal with this?

Here is the full console Xcode's output:

```
>     2020-03-16 17:55:17.549 xcodebuild[56626:765857]  DTDeviceKit: deviceType from 3ad4f96e876e8222a72563420303530067367818 was NULL
>     ** BUILD FAILED **
> 
> 
> Xcode's output: ↳



  **Skipped Warnings about deprecated methods, because of char limits and previously builds despite the warnings.** 


> 
>     Compiler message:
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.0/lib/src/http_request_data_reader.dart:11:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
>     import 'dart:html';
>            ^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart:6:8:
> Error: Not found: 'dart:html'
>     import 'dart:html';
>            ^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.0/lib/src/http_request_data_reader.dart:28:10:
> Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.
>       Future<HttpRequest> _getString(String url, HttpRequest xhr) {
>              ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.0/lib/src/http_request_data_reader.dart:28:46:
> Error: Type 'HttpRequest' not found.
>       Future<HttpRequest> _getString(String url, HttpRequest xhr) {
>                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart:34:18:
> Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
>       final _xhrs = <HttpRequest>{};
>                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.0/lib/src/http_request_data_reader.dart:20:23:
> Error: Method not found: 'HttpRequest'.
>         var request = new HttpRequest();
>                           ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.0/lib/src/http_request_data_reader.dart:28:46:
> Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
>       Future<HttpRequest> _getString(String url, HttpRequest xhr) {
>                                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/intl-0.16.0/lib/src/http_request_data_reader.dart:29:35:
> Error: 'HttpRequest' isn't a type.
>         var completer = new Completer<HttpRequest>();
>                                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:34:
> Error: 'Blob' isn't a type.
>           var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
>                                      ^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart:46:15:
> Error: The method 'HttpRequest' isn't defined for the class
> 'BrowserClient'.
>      - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
>     Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'HttpRequest'.
>         var xhr = HttpRequest();
>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart:58:42:
> Error: The method 'Blob' isn't defined for the class 'BrowserClient'.
>      - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
>     Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'Blob'.
>           var blob = xhr.response as Blob ?? Blob([]);
>                                              ^^^^
>     ../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart:59:20:
> Error: The method 'FileReader' isn't defined for the class
> 'BrowserClient'.
>      - 'BrowserClient' is from 'package:http/src/browser_client.dart' ('../../Developer/flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/http-0.12.0+4/lib/src/browser_client.dart').
>     Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'FileReader'.
>           var reader = FileReader();
>                        ^^^^^^^^^^
>     Unhandled exception:
>     FileSystemException(uri=org-dartlang-untranslatable-uri:dart%3Ahtml;
> message=StandardFileSystem only supports file:* and data:* URIs)
>     #0      StandardFileSystem.entityForUri (package:front_end/src/api_prototype/standard_file_system.dart:33:7)
>     #1      asFileUri (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:604:37)
>     #2      writeDepfile (package:vm/kernel_front_end.dart:799:21)
>     <asynchronous suspension>
>     #3      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/frontend_server.dart:472:15)
>     <asynchronous suspension>
>     #4      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:38:22)
>     #5      starter (package:flutter_frontend_server/server.dart:149:27)
>     #6      main (file:///b/s/w/ir/cache/builder/src/flutter/flutter_frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
>     #7      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:305:32)
>     #8      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:174:12)
> 
>     Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception: Errors during snapshot creation: null
>     Failed to build bundle.
>     Failed to package /Users/[user]/StudioProjects/[projectName]/ios/...
>     Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
>     note: Using new build system
>     note: Planning build
>     note: Constructing build description
> 
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
> 
> Error launching application on [user].
```

EDIT: I also have "platform :ios, '11.0'" in my Podfile and iOS Deployment Target set to 11.0 on Pods settings.

EDIT 2: Here are the packages I use:

> dependencies: flutter: sdk: flutter
>
> flutter_localizations: sdk: flutter
>
> flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
>
> geoflutterfire: ^2.0.3+5
>
> firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
>
> cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+6
>
> firebase_core: ^0.4.0+9
>
> firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
>
> firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9
>
> firebase_database: ^3.0.7
>
> firebase_admob: ^0.9.0+7
>
> flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
>
> font_awesome_flutter: ^8.5.0
>
> image_picker: ^0.6.1+11
>
> image: ^2.1.4
>
> rxdart: ^0.22.1
>
> location: ^2.3.5
>
> google_maps_flutter: ^0.5.20+1
>
> geocoder: ^0.2.1
>
> google_sign_in: ^4.0.11
>
> provider: ^4.0.4
>
> flutter_inapp_purchase: ^2.0.4
>
> http: ^0.12.0+4
>
> url_launcher: ^5.2.5
>
> intl: ^0.16.0
>
> cloud_functions: ^0.4.1+4
>
> apple_sign_in: ^0.1.0
>
> flutter_signin_button: ^1.0.0
>
> json_annotation: ^3.0.1
>
> notification_permissions: ^0.4.4
>
> html_unescape: ^1.0.1+3
>
> cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
>
> dev_dependencies: 
>   flutter_test:  sdk:  flutter build_runner: ^1.7.3 json_serializable:
>   ^3.2.5

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `intl` package needs to be properly configured to work on Flutter.

When you import it, DON'T use the `import 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart';`, insead use the follwing (each one has its use so see the docs the one that best suits you):

```dart
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl_standalone.dart';
```

Comment: I'm not using dart:html... It's a part of the intl and some other packages. I just started new project from scratch, using the same packages and it compiles fine. I have no idea what went wrong with this one... One thing I know for sure is I have no intend to make a web app and this "browser_client.dart:6:8:" is used only for web apps, so the error is something in this direction, but I have no idea what happened. I tried flutter config --no-enable-web... just in case I enabled the web somehow, but still doesn't work.

Comment: Have you configured the `intl` package correctly? You have to import it the right way otherwise it loads the Browser version, how does your intl imports look like? Are you using `import 'package:intl/intl_browser.dart';`?

Comment: no I don't but I saw this import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_http_request.dart'; and I wasn't using it. I commented it and now get this error flutter dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/AppAuth.framework/AppAuth so I have to find a way to get rid of it to see if there were a problem with the import.

Comment: Also check if you are using the latest version of the `intl` library and do a `flutter clean`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I’ll give it a try tomorrow, and let you know if it works

Comment: Ok I'm accepting the answer because the project compiled for Android. I can't test on iPhone yet because there's still an issue with the AppAuth library.